# Overflow Exception Occured: Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow

Tags: c#, oracle10g

I got the error "Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow." when execute the following condition

```
long countryCode = Convert.ToInt64(dr["Country_Code"]);
                    double curValue = Convert.ToDouble(dr["Conversion_Rate"]);
                    string selectSql = " SELECT NVL ((ABS ( " + curValue + " - AVG (conversion_rate)) / AVG (conversion_rate)) * 100,0) AS rate_deviation" +
                                       " FROM " + DBObjects.TABLE_ODS_CURRENCY_CONVERSIONS + " WHERE country_code = " + countryCode;

DataTable dtDeviation = this.ServerCfgReader.DefaultDBProvider.DBDataAccess.GetSqlSelection(selectSql);
```

When i execute the condition in SQL, the above query got **Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow exception** occured..

Any suggestion to resolve this problem.

Comment: Not directly relevant to your question, but you should really be using parameters instead of building your query like this.

Comment: Are you sure it's the query and not one of those converts causing the exception?

Answer (score 0):

Convert.ToInt64.... use a double instead.

Also, when building SQL like that use string builder instead, its much more efficient...

```
double countryCode = Convert.ToDouble(dr["Country_Code"]);
double curValue = Convert.ToDouble(dr["Conversion_Rate"]);

StringBuilder selectSql = new StringBuilder();
selectSql.AppendFormat(" SELECT NVL ((ABS ( {0} - AVG (conversion_rate)) / AVG (conversion_rate)) * 100,0) AS rate_deviation ",curValue );
selectSql.AppendFormat(" FROM {0} ", DBObjects.TABLE_ODS_CURRENCY_CONVERSIONS);
selectSql.AppendFormat(" WHERE country_code = {0}",countryCode);


DataTable dtDeviation = this.ServerCfgReader.DefaultDBProvider.DBDataAccess.GetSqlSelection(selectSql.ToString());
```

failing that, read this: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/89392-arithmetic-operation-resulted-in-an-overflow/

maybe your numbers are too large to handle as Doubles too???